# Android Unable To Send Request Despite Cleartext Traffic Enabled In Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unirest

I have been using unirest to call a weather API (https://rapidapi.com/community/api/open-weather-map/) after trying many of the common solutions it still provides an error.

Here is a re-creation of what creates the error.

```
// Java
    @RequiresApi(api = VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void GetWeather(View view) throws UnirestException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/find?q=london&cnt=0&mode=null&lon=0&type=link%2C%20accurate&lat=0&units=imperial%2C%20metric")
                        .header("x-rapidapi-key", "<KEY>")
                        .header("x-rapidapi-host", "community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com")
                        .asJson();

                System.out.println(response.getBody());
                System.out.println("Test");
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

And the Error It Creates:

> 2021-07-03 20:59:40.553 15665-15783/com.example.weather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
> Process: com.example.weather, PID: 15665
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes4.dex)
> at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
> at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:194)
> at kong.unirest.apache.SecurityConfig.createDefaultRegistry(SecurityConfig.java:85)
> at kong.unirest.apache.SecurityConfig.buildSocketFactory(SecurityConfig.java:75)
> at kong.unirest.apache.SecurityConfig.createManager(SecurityConfig.java:59)
> at kong.unirest.apache.ApacheClient.(ApacheClient.java:54)
> at kong.unirest.-$$Lambda$LzMzt6m8SiUmve_yOIZRwHx_kH8.apply(Unknown Source:4)
> at kong.unirest.Config.buildClient(Config.java:755)
> at kong.unirest.Config.getClient(Config.java:740)
> at kong.unirest.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:241)
> at com.example.weather.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:43)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> 2021-07-03 20:59:40.645 15665-15783/com.example.weather I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15665 SIG: 9

What I've tried to fix this:

- as can be seen in above I first tried threading the request
- then a @RequiresApi(api = VERSION_CODES.O)
- in androidManifest I have added:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

- and made a network_security_config.xml containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" >
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

To check if the request was faulty I ran it in IntelliJ which was able to return the data, so what am I missing?

Or should I not be using Unirest with android, I have used retrofit in the past and that has worked although Unirest seems to be more concise.